# Remove widthSegments and heightSegments in PlaneGeometry threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, shapes, jsfiddle

I am trying to remove the `widthSegments` and `heightSegments`.

If i change this

```
var tergeo= new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 1, 1);
```

to

```
var tergeo= new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 0, 0);
```

It does not work

How can i remove **widthSegments** and **heightSegments** in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLt8512r/4/) ?

Comment: That's really curious, why do you want to have zero segmentation on a plane. If you need a "plane" of quads, made with line segments, then have a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/wireframe-of-quads/17924

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i just need just a rectangle with borders color ( no segments and filling colors )

Comment: Then, why do you use `PlaneGeometry` at all? Use an indexed buffer geometry of 4 points with `LineBasicMaterial()` for `Line()` object.

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks, if you can pass me some code examples it would be great, i am beginner with three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with an indexed buffer geometry:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let g = QuadGeometry(THREE.MathUtils.randInt(5, 10), THREE.MathUtils.randInt(5, 10));
let m = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"});
let quad = new THREE.Line(g, m);
scene.add(quad);

function QuadGeometry(w, h){
  let pts = [
    [0.5, 0.5], 
    [-0.5, 0.5], 
    [-0.5, -0.5], 
    [0.5, -0.5]
  ].map(p => {return new THREE.Vector2(p[0], p[1])});
  let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);
  g.setIndex([0, 1, 2, 3, 0]);
  g.scale(w, h, 1);
  
  return g;
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```